# Как запустить google maps intent с правильным Uri для маршрута

Tags: android, google-maps-api

Доброго времени суток, столкнулся с проблемой - не могу найти, как запустить google maps intent таким образом, чтобы, передавая туда координаты или адрес точки, был сразу проложен маршрут от текущего местоположения.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вообще, есть [официальная дока](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/android-intents).

Самое простое:

```
// создаём Uri из координат
Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse("google.streetview:cbll=46.414382,10.013988");

// создаём сам Intent
Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri);

// Помечаем его как explicit
mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");

// пытаемся запустить
startActivity(mapIntent);
```

Чтоб включить навигацию при создании `Uri` передаём `google.navigation`.
Формат:

```
google.navigation:q=a+street+address
google.navigation:q=latitude,longitude
```

Параметры:

- `q`: конечная точка для поиска. Это может быть широта + долгота или отформатированный адрес. Если запрос возвращает более одного результата, будет выбран первый.
- `mode` задаём метод передвижения. Опциональный параметр, по-умолчанию это "на автомобиле". Возможные значения:

  1. `d` - на машине
  2. `w` - пешком
  3. `b` - велосипед
- `avoid` задаёт объекты, который маршрут должен избегать. Опциональный параметр. Возможные значения:

  1. `t` - платные проезд
  2. `h` - шоссе
  3. `f` - паром

Пример:

```
Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse("google.navigation:q=Taronga+Zoo,+Sydney+Australia");
Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri);
mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
startActivity(mapIntent);
```

Comment: большое спасибо

Comment: @skiff2011 всегда рад помочь ^_^